# Given definition of function in Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 3 on functions, does $f(x)$ have to be a real number or any number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question regards what it means for a function not to be defined for certain numbers.

In Spivak Chapter 3, two definitions are given of function. The first is a "provisional" definition, meant to kickstart the discussion on functions:

> A function is a rule which assigns, to each of certain real numbers,
> some other real number

The second definition is supposed to be the "first full-fledged definition" in the book:

> A function is a collection of pairs of numbers with the following
> property: if $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ are both in the collection, then $b=c$; in
> other words, the collection must not contain two different pairs with
> the same first element.

The first thing I note with with second definition is that it does not constrain the numbers to real numbers.

In problem 3 of the chapter problems we are asked to find the domain of some given functions.

The definition of domain from this chapter is

> If $f$ is a function, the domain of $f$ is the set of all $a$ for
> which there is some $b$ such that $(a,b)$ is in $f$. If $a$ is in the
> domain of $f$, it follows from the definition of a function that there
> is, in fact, a unique number $b$ such that $(a,b)$ is in $f$. This
> unique $b$ is denoted by $f(a)$.

Problem 3a:

> a) Find domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

My reasoning is that if $1-x^2<0$ then $f(x)$ isn't a real number, though I am not sure I obtained this conclusion from the definitions and derivations so far in the book. But $f(x)$ is still **a number**, and so the pair $(x,f(x))$ exists.

So, is the definition of function missing something (a restriction to real numbers), or is there something wrong with how I am justifying that $x$ can be any number because as function has been defined, $f(x)$ can be any number, even non-real?

Comment: Unless there is an explicit mention otherwise, I'm fairly certain that Spivak (and pretty much any author of a calculus or real analysis text) assumes "number" means "real number".

Comment: For the domain of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ you are definitely meant to assume real numbers. This seems sloppy of Spivak, due to lack of specificity and because much math deals with functions with  domains and ranges which contain no numbers. For now, treat “number” to mean real number, unless otherwise specified. Most of beginning calculus is about real numbers.